# Phone touchscreen protector on a laptop touchpad?

Tags: touchscreen

I have a laptop which came with a sticker on the touchpad, which is a good idea, same wear protection as a phone, except that the sticker has an annoying texture. (lenovo t510 thinkpad)

I bough a cheap phone screen protector for 1 euro, and i dont know if it is resistive or capacitive. Can i use a phone screen protector on the laptop? some place sell laptop touchpad stickers for 20 dollars, crazy?!

lenovo touchpad sticker:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it? You can get a screen protector for less than a dollar on eBay. Get a pair of capacitive and resistive and try them.

Comment: i could mess up the Lenovo sticker if i pull it off and the other doesnt work. i dont know what's under, i have to try rubbing alcohol to prepare the surface, maybe it can be used without a sticker until i find something suitable. will see.

Comment: try pressing operating it with with a stick or plastic rod, if that works it's resistive, else it's capacitive.

Comment: is there a special stylus for that touchpad?

Comment: Thanks... cool advice! I have stuck an sony experia protector instead of the IBM one. It was full of gum glue so i had to use white spirit first to get that off and then alcohol to get white spirit residues from the PC, and the Experia touchpad is at least a vast improvement compared to the Lenovo one. more performant and feels nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I just put a plastic screen protector left over from my phone, on my Asus laptop's touchpad and it is sooo much better. My touchpad has some kind of faux glass surface (bit I think it's actually just metal), similar to the one on the Zenbooks but not that good and I always had trouble with it, pointer not so precise and my fingers would sometimes not glide on it properly. Now it is soo much better. I recommed trying it for anyone who has trouble with the touchpad, and if it doesn't work out, you can easily remove it and dump it in the trash can :)

I actually considered dumping this (cheapish) laptop and buying the more expensive Zenbook, just for the touchpad, but I don't need to anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

From direct experiment i can say that a touch phone protector works fine on a PC touchpad. compared to a genuine PC touchpad, the phone protector is slightly too smooth and you may want to try abrading it with a 800/1000 grit sandpaper first to have an rougher touchpad surface. 
So far it's much better than the sticker the Thinkpad arrived with.

requires white spirit and rubbing alcohol and a touchscreen phone protector in that order and a razor blade, trace the outline of the toucharea with paper and then cut through the paper and phone protector and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use nanotechnology liquid glass screen protector. It gives shatter resistance and scratch proof protection.

Comment: Have you some sources about?